# Comment gérer le "Demander à" suivi d'un nombre imprécis de personnes ?

Tags: grammaire, formulation

Par exemple, je dois déménager et veut demander de l'aide à mes amis. J'ai du mal à formuler la phrase suivante :

> "Il faut que je demande à entre 5 et 10 amis de venir m'aider pour déménager."

Cependant, la formulation "à entre" ne me semble pas grammaticalement correcte. À l'oral, on pourrait dire :

> "Il faut que je demande à 5-10 personnes de venir m'aider pour déménager."

Mes questions sont donc :

1. La formulation "à entre" est grammaticalement correcte ?
2. Si elle ne l'est pas, peut-on utiliser la deuxième formulation **dans un écrit soutenu** ?
3. Si ce n'est toujours pas le cas, comment contourner le problème ? (Si possible, sans changer le verbe demander. En effet, ici on pourrait le remplacer par le verbe appeler, mais ce changement dépend du contexte et appeler ne conviendrait pas à toutes les situations.)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98141/discussion-on-question-by-otdm-comment-gerer-le-demander-a-suivi-dun-nombre-i).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. *La formulation "à entre" est-elle grammaticalement correcte ?*

La tournure ***à entre x et y*** est très courante à l'oral, et se rencontre parfois à l'écrit sans choquer grand monde.

On trouve quand même au moins une condamnation, de [TermiumPlus](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/clefsfp/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_catlog_a&page=9dmTt1z7MHA0.html):

> L’emploi de la préposition à n’est pas compatible avec celui de la préposition entre, qui exprime un intervalle.
>
> Pour indiquer une somme ou un chiffre approximatif se situant entre deux sommes ou deux chiffres, on peut employer la préposition à et la conjonction ou :
>
> Le total se chiffre à 4 500 $ ou 5 000 $. (et non : à entre 4 500 et 5 000 $)

Cette suggestion peut passer pour une somme d'argent mais n'est pas vraiment satisfaisante dans le cas de la question qui donnerait :

> Il faut que je demande à 5 ou 10 amis de venir m'aider pour déménager.

La phrase risquera d'être comprise comme excluant les valeurs de six à neuf, ce qui prêtera à confusion.

Voici quelques exemples d'utilisation qui montrent bien la présence de la forme *à entre* à l'écrit :

Le [JDD](https://www.lejdd.fr/Societe/Les-gens-ne-prennent-pas-l-esperanto-au-serieux-744252)

> les estimations dont on dispose portent le nombre d’usagers **à entre 500.000 et 2 millions**.

[Actu.fr](https://actu.fr/normandie/flers_61169/flers-quelques-bonnes-raisons-participer-concours-dorthographe-ce-samedi_21750628.html)

> J’ai participé **à entre 150 et 200 concours**.

Christianisme et neurosciences: Pour une théologie de l’animal humain
De Alexandre Ganoczy

> Il manque en effet des vestiges fossilisés pour combler scientifiquement l'intervalle que la recherche actuelle estime **à entre trois et cinq millions d'années**.

[Population et santé dans les pays en développement, Centre de recherche pour le développement international](https://www.idrc.ca/sites/default/files/openebooks/992-5/index.html)

> Fourchette des âges auxquels les femmes peuvent procréer, définie à des fins statistiques **à entre 15 et 44 ans**, ou entre 15 et 49 ans.

[Communiqué de presse des Nations Unies](https://www.un.org/press/fr/2009/ENVDEV1069.doc.htm)

> S’exprimant au nom de l’Union européenne, dont son pays assure la présidence, M. Fredrik Reinfeldt, Premier Ministre de la Suède, a estimé **à entre 5 et 7 milliards** d’euros le montant des ressources nécessaires pour l’adaptation des pays en développement aux effets des changements climatiques au cours des deux prochaines années.

La phrase proposée dans la question paraît donc acceptable :

> Il faut que je demande à entre 5 et 10 amis de venir m'aider pour déménager.

Puisqu'un registre soutenu est attendu, il vaut mieux écrire les nombres en toutes lettres et utiliser la préposition *à* plutôt que *pour* :

> Il faut que je demande à entre cinq et dix amis de venir m'aider à déménager.

Ou en conservant *pour* :

> Il faut que je demande à entre cinq et dix amis de venir m'aider pour mon déménagement.

---

2. *Si elle ne l'est pas, peut-on utiliser la deuxième formulation dans un écrit soutenu ?*

Cette variante est possible, mais il faut alors utiliser un tiret moyen pour indiquer qu'il s'agit d'un intervalle :

> Il faut que je demande à 5–10 personnes de venir m'aider pour déménager.

L'intervalle se lira *...à de cinq à dix personnes...* ou *...à cinq, dix personnes...*

Dans ce dernier cas, on pourra aussi directement écrire :

> Il faut que je demande à cinq, dix personnes de venir m'aider pour déménager.

---

3. *Si ce n'est toujours pas le cas, comment contourner le problème ?*

Dans un registre soutenu, on peut rédiger la phrase comme ceci :

> Il faut que je demande à cinq à dix de mes amis de venir m'aider à déménager.

Comment: "*5 à 10*" me paraît le choix le plus évident et naturel, je me demande pourquoi il n'est pas mentionné plus  dans les réponses.

Answer (score 2):

1. Pas très stylé mais très utilisé dans le langage courant.
2. Dans un cadre formel, je préférerais une autre tournure, car c'est plus du langage parlé courant qu'écrit et formel.
3. La formulation que j'utiliserais est une des suivantes, en fonction de mes relations avec le destinataire :

   a. "*je dois demander à un certain nombre d'amis, sûrement compris entre 5 et 10, de venir m'aider à déménager.*"

   b. "*j'ai besoin de 5 à 10 personnes pour venir m'aider à déménager, je vais demander à des amis/connaissances.*"

   c. "*Il me faut 5 à 10 paires de bras pour m'aider à déménager, je vais demander à des amis.*"

Il est toujours possible de remplacer le nombre indéterminé par "*X*", mais c'est plus courant que formel, pour moi (mais ce n'est qu'une opinion). Ex. "*J'ai besoin de X personnes (de 5 à 10 certainement) pour m'aider à déménager, je vais demander à des amis.*"

Answer (score -4):

1/ Non, ce n'est pas correct ; ceci l'est (il vaut mieux dire « aider à ») ;

- Il faut que je demande à des amis, de 5 à 10 d'entre eux, de venir m'aider à déménager.

2/ « à 5 et 10 » ne me semble pas être très bon ;

- Il faut que je demande à plusieurs personnes, de cinq à dix, de venir m'aider à déménager.
- Je dois demander à plus de cinq personnes, peut-être jusqu'à dix, de venir m'aider à déménager.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97532/discussion-on-answer-by-lph-comment-gerer-le-demander-a-suivi-dun-nombre-impr).